# How to setup bootable RAID 0 on remote server

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, grub, raid0

I have a remote server with 2 identical 500Gb SSD, `sda` and `sdb`. A rescue mode is also available from the cloud provider's interface.
How to get Debian installed on a bootable RAID 0?

I understand I have to boot on the rescue mode and partition the disks as the following:

```
sda1   499Gb   empty
sda2   100Mb   grub
sdb1   500Gb   empty
```

Then install and create an ext4 RAID 0 on `sda1` and `sdb1` using `mdadm`. Download and install Debian from the ISO to the RAID0 partition. Install a GRUB on `sda2`.

Is that correct?
Do you have a step-by-step guide?

Comment: Didn't the cloud provider provide any directions? Who is it?

Comment: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Softwareraid/en

Comment: "How to setup bootable RAID 0 on remote server" - I'd be asking myself why first of all

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason for using RAID 0, you might consider using LVM to put both  sda1 and sdb1 in a single volume group.

Comment: LVM should be fine as well